# How to serialize DigitalPersona fingerprint template in Delphi

Tags: delphi, activex, ole, fingerprint, delphi-xe6

I'm having a big difficulty trying to serialize DigitalPersona fingerprint templates. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm able to Deserialize the template from a file that was saved from the demo EXE that is distributed with the SDK and verify the template without problems with this code in my application

```
procedure TFMain.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Blob: Array [0 .. 1632] of Byte;
  VarBlob: OleVariant;
  MyFile: File;
  P: Pointer;
  Teste: TDPFPTemplate;
begin
  // Read binary data from file.
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    AssignFile(MyFile, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    Reset(MyFile, 1632);
    BlockRead(MyFile, Blob, 1);
    CloseFile(MyFile);
    VarBlob := VarArrayCreate([0, Length(Blob) - 1], varByte);
    P := VarArrayLock(VarBlob);
    try
      Move(Blob[0], P^, Length(Blob));
    finally
      VarArrayUnlock(VarBlob);
    end;
    if not Assigned(Template) then
    begin
      Teste := TDPFPTemplate.Create(Self);
      Template := Teste.DefaultInterface;
      Template.Deserialize(VarBlob);
    end;
  end;
```

But when I try to serialize the template to save to a file in my application, the data being written in the file seems to have nothing to do with the template, because I checked the file contents and they are very, very different in structure. All I'm doing is to call the Serialize method of the IDPFPTemplate interface as it's told on the SDK docs. But, when I try to verify the fingerprint using the file I generated by my application the fingerprint cannot be verified because the contents of the file are invalid. Here is the code to serialize and save the file

```
procedure TFMain.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyFile: File;
  OleBlob: OleVariant;
  Blob: Array of Byte;
  uBound: Integer;
begin
  {Template is a global variable in the main form that is set by the
   enroll process, I can verify the template set by the enroll
   process, but I'm not able to record it and verify it later. The
   Serialize method returns an OleVariant containing an Array of
   Bytes}
  OleBlob := Template.Serialize;
  if VarArrayDimCount(OleBlob) = 1 then
  begin
    uBound := VarArrayHighBound(OleBlob, 1);
  end;

  if uBound < 0 then
    ShowMessage('Template vazio')
  else
  begin
    Blob := OleBlob;
    AssignFile(MyFile, 'c:\users\leandro\desktop\teste.txt');
    ReWrite(MyFile, 1632);
    BlockWrite(MyFile, Blob, 1);
    CloseFile(MyFile);
  end;
end;
```

Note that the size of the template is always 1632 bytes, that's why my array is 1632 bytes long. Is there something wrong in the way I'm recording the array contents on the file or with the call to the SDK's Serialize method to generate invalid template data into the file?

Comment: I believe that you are not converting correctly OleBlob(OleVariant) to Blob(array of byte).

Comment: Save the OleVariant to stream, save it to the file and tell us the result. An example - http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=2263

Comment: @RBA, I tried doing as suggested on the site you pointed, but the result is the same. I can't verify the fingerprint because the template has invalid data. I'm completely lost because I can read the template without problems, but I'm not able to record it yet.

Comment: What kind of variant the `Template.Serialize` is returning??

Comment: @FabricioAraujo, I checked the returned type with Delphi debugger and the watch says OleBlob is a Variant Array of Bytes and the serialize return type is OleVariant